# Ruby uninitialized constant Job (NameError) Scraping and adding to database

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, initialization, constants, nameerror

I am creating a scraper with `Nokogiri` and `Ruby on Rails`. My goal is to scrape jobs from a specific webpage. I created the following code, which results in an array of job titles. So this works fine.

My problem is now, that I want to add these titles to my database of Vacancies. When I type in `Vacancy.create(companyname=jobs[0])`, it should create a `Vacancy` with the first job-title in the array.

But it gives me an error instead:

> app/services/job_service.rb:18:in `': uninitialized constant
>   Vacancy (NameError)

So it looks like it does not know the class `Vacancy`.
I therefore required the file vacancy.rb:

```
require_relative(../models/vacancy.rb')
```

But then it gives me another error:

> uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord (NameError)

So I now think that I am doing something fundamentally wrong here.
Am I putting the whole scraper file in the wrong folder (should I probably put it in the rake folder)?. All I want is to execute something like `Vacancy.create` so that it pushes this to my database of Vacancies (aka Jobs).

Here is the the scraper (job_service.rb):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

url = "https://www.savedroid.com/#karriere-section"

html_file = open(url).read
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)
jobs = []
html_doc.search('.job').each do |element|
  jobs << element.text.strip
end


Vacancy.create(companyname=jobs[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the model is created and there are necessary fields in the table

let's put you code of parser into the rails services:

```
class Jobs
  def self.jobs
    return @jobs if @jobs

    require 'open-uri'
    require 'nokogiri'

    url = "https://www.savedroid.com/#karriere-section"

    html_file = open(url).read
    html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)
    jobs = []

    html_doc.search('.job').each do |element|
      jobs << element.text.strip
    end

    @jobs = jobs
  end
end
```

then you can call it inside rails controller:

```
VacancyController < ApplicationController
  def create
    Jobs.jobs.each do |job|
      Vacancy.create(companyname: job)
    end
  end
end
```